# how to enable/disable a component in extjs based on radio field select

Tags: extjs

I want to enable/disable a component in extjs based on radio field select.
Here is my code:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    vertical: 'false',
    columns: 2,
    width: 400,
    items: [{
        boxLabel: 'Select time interval',
        name: 'timeInterval',
        id: 'timeIntervalPanel',
        checked: true,
        inputValue: 'timeInterval',
        listeners: {
            change: function () {
                Ext.getCmp('timeIntervalPanel').enable();
            }
        }

    }, {
        boxLabel: 'Last Measurement Collected',
        name: 'timeInterval',
        id: 'LastMeasurement',
        inputValue: 'lastMeasuremnet',
        listeners: {
            change: function () {
                Ext.getCmp('timeIntervalPanel').disable();
            }
        }
    }]

}, {
    id: 'timeIntervalPanel',
    xtype: 'optima-timeintervalpanel',
    name: 'timeIntervalPanel',
    text: 'select',
    endDate: new Date(),
    startDate: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -30),
    disabled: true
}]
```

Comment: tried enable and disable methods by making component as disabled true

Comment: i want to enable and disable  timeIntervalPanel based on radio field select

Comment: Which version of extjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have id duplication in the first radio item, and in the component with xtype `optima-timeintervalpanel`. Removing the `id: 'timeIntervalPanel'` from your first radio item fixes the problem.

Here is a working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26sl

**EDIT**

A similar approach as [@njdhv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3519009/njdhv) used (specifying a change event listener to the radio group), but somehow simplified:

```
listeners: {
    change: function(radiogrup, value) {
        Ext.getCmp('timeIntervalPanel').setDisabled(
            value.timeInterval === 'timeInterval'
        );
    }
}
```

Working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26t6

Comment: thank you for solution but it's not enabling the date filed when "select time interval" is selected  it's enabling when last measurement is selected

Comment: i want to enable date field when "select time interval" is selected

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs docs **RadioGroup** have change event. You can put your logic inside change event of **RadioGroup**. For more details can refer [ExtJs docs for RadioGroup](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.form.RadioGroup.html#event-change)

I have create small demo to show you as per your requirement, how it work. [Sencha fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26sk)

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'RadioGroup Example enable/disable button on change',
    width: '100%',
    height: 500,
    itemId: 'myPanel',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        defaults: {
            xtyple:'button',
            disabled:true,
            handler:function(){
                Ext.Msg.alert('Click','This button is enable..!');
            }
        },
        items: [{
            html: 'predefinedDateButton',
            itemId: 'predefined'
        }, {
            html: 'lastXDateButton',
            itemId: 'lasthours'
        }, {
            html: 'specifyDateButton',
            itemId: 'specifydate'
        }]
    }],
    items: [, {
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        vertical: 'true',
        columns: 1,
        width: 200,
        listeners: {
            change: function (rf, newValue, oldValue) {
                var myPanel = rf.up('#myPanel');
                myPanel.down('toolbar').items.items.map(item => {
                    item.setDisabled(true);
                })
                myPanel.down(`#${newValue.timeInterval}`).setDisabled(false);
            }
        },
        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'Select Predefined interval',
            name: 'timeInterval',
            id: 'selectPredefinedInterval',
            inputValue: 'predefined'

        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Specify last X hours/days',
            name: 'timeInterval',
            id: 'SpecifyLastHours',
            inputValue: 'lasthours'

        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Specify date or interval',
            name: 'timeInterval',
            id: 'specifiedDate',
            inputValue: 'specifydate'
        }]
    }]
});
```